# Dozer map list with annotations

Tags: java, dozer

How to correctly map the map using Dozer and annotations

Without lists, everything works well

Dozer version 6.1.0

http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/collectionandarraymapping.html
How to render b-hint on annotations

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_THEME")
@Data
public class ProductTheme implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "PRODUCT_THEME_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PRODUCT_THEME_SEQ", sequenceName = "PRODUCT_THEME_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @Mapping("id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 100)
    @Mapping("description")
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "PRODUCT_THEME_IMAGE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "THEME_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                                    @JoinColumn(name = "IMAGE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })

    **@Mapping("imagesList")**

    private List<Images> imagesList;
    @Column(name = "ACTIVE", nullable = false)
    @Mapping("active")
    private Boolean active;
...
}
```

Everything works fine, but when I try to get a map list, I get an error

How can I solve this problem without configuring xml?

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:454)
    at java.util.Vector.toString(Vector.java:1000)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.toString(IndirectList.java:890)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at by.softclub.model.entity.Images.toString(Images.java:15)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.util.Vector.toString(Vector.java:1000)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.toString(IndirectList.java:890)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at by.softclub.model.entity.ProductTheme.toString(ProductTheme.java:21)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.util.Vector.toString(Vector.java:1000)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.toString(IndirectList.java:890)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at by.softclub.model.entity.Images.toString(Images.java:15)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.util.Vector.toString(Vector.java:1000)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.toString(IndirectList.java:890)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at by.softclub.model.entity.ProductTheme.toString(ProductTheme.java:21)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.util.Vector.toString(Vector.java:1000)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.toString(IndirectList.java:890)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at by.softclub.model.entity.Images.toString(Images.java:15)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.util.Vector.toString(Vector.java:1000)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.toString(IndirectList.java:890)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at by.softclub.model.entity.ProductTheme.toString(ProductTheme.java:21)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.util.Vector.toString(Vector.java:1000)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.toString(IndirectList.java:890)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at by.softclub.model.entity.Images.toString(Images.java:15)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.util.Vector.toString(Vector.java:1000)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.toString(IndirectList.java:890)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at by.softclub.model.entity.ProductTheme.toString(ProductTheme.java:21)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.util.Vector.toString(Vector.java:1000)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.toString(IndirectList.java:890)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at by.softclub.model.entity.Images.toString(Images.java:15)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.util.Vector.toString(Vector.java:1000)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.toString(IndirectList.java:890)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at by.softclub.model.entity.ProductTheme.toString(ProductTheme.java:21)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.util.Vector.toString(Vector.java:1000)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.toString(IndirectList.java:890)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at by.softclub.model.entity.Images.toString(Images.java:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Error was in сompatibility  @Date (@toString) from Lomdok and Dozer

Answer (score 0):

To prevent lombok's `ToString()` to run recursively the link field should be excluded. And the same for `hashCode()`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_THEME")
@Data
@lombok.ToString(exclude="imagesList")
@lombok.EqualsAndHashCode(exclude="imagesList")
public class ProductTheme implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```